# Are cx-freezed executables hackable

Tags: python, cx-freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can EXE generated by cx_freeze be completely decompiled back to readable Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497399/can-exe-generated-by-cx-freeze-be-completely-decompiled-back-to-readable-python)

I've used cx-freeze to convert a python script to an executable. Is it possible to reverse that? Can I get my python script from the binary cx-freeze has generated?

**EDIT**. This is a practical question. I really need to recover one cx-freezed executable to a more-less readable form. Does anyone have a recipie of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Any 'frozen' PY application can be <strike>disassembled but not really</strike> **decompiled**. With enough time and patience someone would be able to reverse-engineer nearly any program (including yours).

**Edit**
Correction as per comments below.

Comment: "can not be really decompiled" -- `[citation needed]`

Comment: Can one recover the python bytecode from the cx-freezed binary? If so, then I'd try to use this tool: https://github.com/gstarnberger/uncompyle, which claims to be able to restore code by reading the bytecode.

Comment: Yes, python bytecode can be recovered from the frozen exe. This is disassembling NOT decompiling. Can you then return that bytecode to a readable format? Yes. Will it be the original source code? No.

Comment: Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: @facha Does anyone know how to do what? Turn python bytecode to human readable format? Yes. If you're looking to 'secure' Python code, cx_freeze will not help you from a user who knows how to work around it.

Comment: @facha: The Python bytecode is stored in a zip file. Depending on how you've frozen it, that might be a separate file with the executable, or it might be appended to the executable. If you can't see a zip file, try unzipping the executable itself.