# Can human-readable source code be recovered from a py2exe executable?

Tags: python, py2exe

I would like to distribute a .exe program that I made with Python and py2exe.
My program may be commercial (not sure). If so, I don't want people to recover easily the sourcecode. (Of course reverse engineering or complex decompiling can always be done, but...)

So : **is it possible to recover the *original* sourecode from an executable produced by py2exe?**

Comment: Linked to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497399/can-exe-generated-by-cx-freeze-be-completely-decompiled-back-to-readable-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, trivially. Py2exe just creates a zip of the .pyc files with an executable wrapper, and those files are easily uncompilable with eg `uncompyle`.

The way to sell commercial software in Python is not to worry about whether people can see the code, but to license it appropriately.

Comment: So there is absolutely no solution for protecting the sourcecode ?

The code has nothing special, but there are algorithms in them for which I don't want the (commercial) competitors to re-use so easily...

Comment: Possible solutions: 1. Don't use Python. 2. Patent your algorithms. 3. Compile to something else? Jython and IronPython? I don't know if that would allow obfuscation. 4. Get a lawyer to sue if they use the algorithms. Add quirks. Use a restrictive license. 5. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Basj http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code

Comment: You're right @DanielRoseman! I tried again a few days ago, and here is the result, it's quite easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497399/can-exe-generated-by-cx-freeze-be-completely-decompiled-back-to-readable-python/62415977#62415977